# Listview from SQLite with buttons

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I have a Listview which retrieve data from SQLite , Listview is for adding attendance it has custom view which contains three buttons . 
**I want to get the selected item when i click any of the three buttons.** 
I am using two methods to load data from SQLite to Listview.
Please Help

```
 public void loadStudentstoAttend()
    {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = GetAllStudentstolist();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, userList, R.layout.row_add_attend,new String[]{"name","roll","semester"}, new int[]{R.id.tv_attend_name, R.id.tv_attend_roll, R.id.tv_attend_sem});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    //GEt All Students to listview to add attendance
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetAllStudentstolist(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        //String sem="'First'";
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db = MyDB.getInstance(this).getReadableDatabase();


            String query = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE semester='"+etSem.getText()+"'";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
                    user.put("name", cursor.getString(0));
                    user.put("roll", cursor.getString(1));
                    user.put("semester", cursor.getString(2));

                    userList.add(user);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return  userList;
    }
```

[This is the custom Layout for ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucahs.png)

Comment: For this you have to write a custom adapter for your listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way that utilises the SimpleCursorAdapter and the XML onClick (some advise against using this, but it's pretty simple to use).

As a Cursor adapter is being used this does require that the table has a column named **_id**

So anyway a solution could be :-

MyDB.java (The database helper) :-

```
public class MyDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "students";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBNAME = "students";
    public static final String COl_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COl_ROLL = "roll";
    public static final String COL_SEMESTER = "semester";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public MyDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME + "(" +
                COl_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COl_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COl_ROLL + " TEXT," +
                COL_SEMESTER + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addStudent(String name, String roll, String semster) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COl_ROLL,roll);
        cv.put(COL_SEMESTER,semster);
        return db.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getStudentList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public int changeStudent(String id, String newname) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_NAME,newname);
        String whereclause = COl_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{id};
        return db.update(TBNAME,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
    }
}
```

- Note COL_ID (you don't need this as you could get the underlying **rowid** but that would likely be more of a pain, **_id** is all you need to be able to identify a row).
- Method **addStudent** allows a student to be added.
- Method **getStudentList** returns all the students as a cursor (all column)
- Method **changeStudent** will change a students name (for demonstration)

The layout (obviously adapt as you need) **row_add_attend.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hidden_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roll"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Present"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="PRESENT"
            android:onClick="clickedPresent"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Absent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ABSENT"
            android:onClick="clickedAbsent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leave"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="LEAVE"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/semester"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

- **Note** **`android:onClick="clickedPresent"`** for the PRESENT button and **`android:onClick="clickedAbsent"`** for the ABSENT button.

The activity (in this case MainActivity) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mLV;
    MyDB mDB;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Cursor mStudentList;
    Button mPresent,mAbsent,mLeave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDB = new MyDB(this);
        addStudents();
        mLV = this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        handleAdapter();
        mLV.setAdapter(mSCA);
    }

    private void handleAdapter() {
        mStudentList = mDB.getStudentList();
        if (mSCA == null) {
            String[] fromcolumns = new String[]{MyDB.COl_NAME,MyDB.COl_ROLL,MyDB.COL_SEMESTER,MyDB.COl_ID};
            int[] toviews = new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.roll,R.id.semester,R.id.hidden_id};
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row_add_attend,mStudentList,fromcolumns,toviews,0);
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mStudentList);
        }
    }

    private void addStudents() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB.getWritableDatabase(),MyDB.TBNAME) == 0) {
            mDB.addStudent("John","12345","First");
            mDB.addStudent("James","543","Second");
        }
    }

    public void clickedPresent(View view) {
        LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
        String id = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.hidden_id)).getText().toString();
        String name = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        String roll = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.roll)).getText().toString();
        String semester = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.semester)).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "PRESENT CLICKED ID is " + id +
                        " Name is " +  name +
                        " Roll is " + roll +
                        " Semester is " + semester
                ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void clickedAbsent(View view) {
        LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
        String id = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.hidden_id)).getText().toString();
        String newname = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString() + " is Absent";
        mDB.changeStudent(id,newname);
        handleAdapter();
    }

        // Should close Cursor when done with it
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mStudentList.close();
        }
}
```

- **Note** that the method names (clickedPresent and clickedAbsent) MUST match what's coded in the layout. The signature must also accept a View.

Running the above and clicking the PRESENT button results in the Toast displaying the relevant details.  Clicking on the ABSENT button changes the name of the respective student to append " is absent" in the database and also refresh the listveiew to show the new data.

Of course you could use the onClick in XML with an associated method in the Activity with the SimpleAdapter. **Note** that `LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();` would have to reflect the hierarchy and types/containers used in your layout.

## Additional

re comment :-

> I have one more little doubt , as you know I am using three buttons so
>   I want to change the color of the button which I press in a selected
>   item the color should be changed only in selected item. how can i do
>   that.

This is quite simple as all you have to do is set the Background colour of the view which is passed to the `onCLick` method.

However, just do doing this, would result in that Button permanently being changed and thus if you clicked all 3 Buttons (note only 2 Present and Absent used in the given example) then all three would be changed.

So to overcome this you could set the background of the other buttons to the original background (original isn't overly easy to find so it's probably easier to set the background to a known colour in the layout (not done in the example below but assumed to be FFAAAAAA)).

However, the underlying logic could be problematic. What do you want to do, is the question you need to ask yourself. If you are setting the state in the DB then at the time you click the button then perhaps fine as the last clicked button would then indicate the state. However, if you wanted to, for example, process the button as per it's state later then you'd have issues determining the state of the button as they aren't intended for this purpose.

Anyway assuming dynamic/real time processing with only one state allowed (aka button selected) then, it's a relatively simple matter of changing the **clickedPresent** and **clickedAbsent** methods as per :-

```
public void clickedPresent(View view) {
    LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
    String id = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.hidden_id)).getText().toString();
    String name = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
    String roll = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.roll)).getText().toString();
    String semester = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.semester)).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "PRESENT CLICKED ID is " + id +
                    " Name is " +  name +
                    " Roll is " + roll +
                    " Semester is " + semester
            ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    lv.findViewById(R.id.Absent).setBackgroundColor(0xFFAAAAAA); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED TO set other button (repeat this leave button)
    view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to set selected button colour
}

public void clickedAbsent(View view) {
    LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
    String id = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.hidden_id)).getText().toString();
    String newname = ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString() + " is Absent";
    lv.findViewById(R.id.Present).setBackgroundColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
    view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);
    mDB.changeStudent(id,newname);
    handleAdapter();
}
```

Here's an example where the first has Present as the currently selected (last clicked) and the second has Absent (note how the other button is a slightly darker grey than the untouched Leave button, showing how FFAAAAAA has been applied as the background colour) :-

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response , I have added the _ID Column but it still says column _id does not exist.
"Create TABLE Students(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR,roll VARCHAR,semester VARCHAR,pass VARCHAR);";

Comment: @User123 did you delete the App's data or uninstall the App after making the change? (the onCreate method only runs once when the database is first created).

Comment: yes I have uninstalled the app from AVD . but other functions work fine only that listview activity is saying column _id does not exist . What should I do , Please Help Me. @MikeT

Comment: Ok the issue is that you have used **_ID** rather than **_id**, normally case doesn't matter BUT there's a bug with the Cursor **`getColumnindex`** method and it is case sensitive. So change `"Create TABLE Students(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR,roll VARCHAR,semester VARCHAR,pass VARCHAR);"` to `"Create TABLE Students(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR,roll VARCHAR,semester VARCHAR,pass VARCHAR);"`. You'll need to uninstall the App and then rerun.

Comment: same also with **`getColumnIndexOrThrow`** method which is what is used/casues the exception, as per `at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:302)`

Comment: I have one more little doubt , as you know I am using three buttons so I want to change the color of the button which I press in a selected item the color should be changed only in selected item. how can i do that. @MikeT

Comment: @User123, the answer has been updated. However, please note that this should really have been asked as another question, as asking multiple questions , or going questions, is outside of the *ask a question about a specific problem*.